# Increasing variance in a time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I can't figure out if this plot has increasing variance or not. From my initial guess of the time plot of aircraft passengers, I would say no but I've taken the difference and it looks like variance is increasing slightly. I've subsequently taken a log transformation and differenced that also where the variance looks to be constant. I'm just wondering is the data variance increasing so much that a log transformation needs to be taken in order to start making the series stationary? I've attached all plots below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems like a statistics question, not a programming question. You may have better luck getting an answer on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Visually I would say that the variance is constant over time.

However, to be sure I would recommend to test the hypothesis using econometric methods such as a White test or Breusch-Pagan test. These tests the hypothesis of constant variance over time.

Comment: Ya it's a tough one could go either way only really noticed a potential variance when looking at differences. I'll take a look at them tests now thank you